# Changed my LG L70 (MS323) runtime from Dalvik to ART and my phone's not working properly. Help?

Tags: art

I switched my LG L70 (MS323)'s runtime from Dalvik to ART, after it restarted and said "Android is upgrading..." and it optimized my 64 apps. After it finishes, I get an error message saying something like Unfortunately the system ui has stopped and then my phone restarts and the whole process starts over again. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

ART is experimental at this stage, unless you're on android L (Lollipop) I wouldn't recommend using it.

If you are stuck in ART you can get back to Dalvik by following this thread: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2707841

Your device should boot then.

Answer (score -3):

Just do a hard reset on your phone.

Comment: Do you mean a [factory reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info)? I'm not sure how simply restarting manually would be sufficient to fix the OP's issue.